# Is there a way to reduce the size of Divi style.css and style.dev.css?

Tags: css

The css file from Divi is really big and it's slowing down the website. I ran the page speed insight by Google and under "Eliminate render-blocking resources", Divi style sheet showed the taking up the largest space load. I've tried searching through other questions but couldn't find a great answer. [screenshot of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb6ms.png)

Comment: How big is the file currently - and what is your target size?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to minify it ? 
You can use a tool online like https://cssminifier.com/ to do the work.

Just paste it on the left box and the save on a file `style.min.css` the result. Then link it to your page and see if it's smaller/faster